# How to keep Previous inputted content when a new Fieldset is added

Tags: javascript, html

Please I am having an issue which i have no idea on how to solve as I am not good with JavaScript.

I am trying to make sure that when an Activity log has been filled and the user choose to add a new Activity. The previous entered content should not be cleared but should remain.

Right about now the contents inputted clears off which is what I don't want. I want the content to remain when a new activity has been added. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Activity Log</title>
   <script>

      // Wait until the window finishes loaded before executing any script
      window.onload = function() {

        // Initialize the activityNumber
        var activityNumber = 6;

        // Select the add_activity button
        var addButton = document.getElementById("add_activity");

        // Select the table element
        var tracklistTable = document.getElementById("tracklist");

        // Attach handler to the button click event
        addButton.onclick = function() {

   // Add a new row to the table using the correct activityNumber
          tracklistTable.innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + activityNumber + '</td><td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog' + activityNumber + '" class="required"></td><td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time' + activityNumber + '" class="required"></td></tr>';

          // Increment the activityNumber
          activityNumber += 1;
        }
 

      }

   </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="leftcol">
              <form name='mainForm' id='mainForm' method="get" action="#">
                <fieldset>
                   <legend>Input Activity Logs</legend>
                   <table id="tracklist">
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">Track List: </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog1" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time1" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog2" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time2" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog3" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time3" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog4" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time4" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>5</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog5" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time5" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
       
                   <input type="submit" />
                </fieldset>
              </form>
              <button id="add_activity">Add Activity</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly editing the inner html, which is going to reset your fields, create a new element (a new table row) and append it to your table with .appendChild. See below. Let me know if you have any questions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Activity Log</title>
   <script>

      // Wait until the window finishes loaded before executing any script
      window.onload = function() {

        // Initialize the activityNumber
        var activityNumber = 6;

        // Select the add_activity button
        var addButton = document.getElementById("add_activity");

        // Select the table element
        var tracklistTable = document.getElementById("tracklist");

        // Attach handler to the button click event
        addButton.onclick = function() {
          // Create New Table Row Element
          var newNode = document.createElement('tr');
          // Set the Inner HTML of that element
          newNode.innerHTML = '<td>' + activityNumber + '</td><td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog' + activityNumber + '" class="required"></td><td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time' + activityNumber + '" class="required"></td>';
         // Append the element to the tracklistTable
          tracklistTable.appendChild(newNode);
          // Increment the activityNumber
          activityNumber += 1;
        }
 

      }

   </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="leftcol">
              <form name='mainForm' id='mainForm' method="get" action="#">
                <fieldset>
                   <legend>Input Activity Logs</legend>
                   <table id="tracklist">
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="3">Track List: </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog1" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time1" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog2" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time2" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog3" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time3" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog4" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time4" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
     <tr>
                      <td>5</td>
                      <td><label>Activity Log: </label><br/><input type="text" name="actlog5" class="required"></td>
                      <td><label>Time: </label><br/><input type="time" name="time5" class="required"></td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
       
                   <input type="submit" />
                </fieldset>
              </form>
              <button id="add_activity">Add Activity</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly